Append redirect_url as query param to login URL through Nuxt Route Middleware
Suppose a user lands on an auth-protected page (say http://localhost:3000/member/profile), my nuxt-base app uses the following middleware to redirect the user to the /login URL:
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {
    const user = useSupabaseUser();
    if (user.value) {
        // already authenticated.
        return;
    }
// append redirect_url to /login so that I can redirect the user back to where they first landed after their authentication.
    return navigateTo(`/login?redirect_url=${from.fullPath}`); 
});


My expected scenario is when the user gets navigated to the http://localhost:3000/login URL by the middlware, I want to make the URL look like this http://localhost:3000/login?redirect_url=%2Fmember%2Fprofile (Note: /member/profile encoded to %2Fmember%2Fprofile
But the middleware is so stubborn and wouldn't allow me to append that query param to login URL. Am I doing this wrong?

Are you sure from.fullPath is encoded URI? You can also try putting it in an extended form - as in ```navigateTo({
path: '/login',
query: {
page: 1,
sort: 'asc'
}
})


I have achieved this by using "from.path" instead of "from.fullPath", and it works fine.
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {
const user = useSupabaseUser();
if (user.value) {
    // already authenticated.
    return;
}

return navigateTo(`/login?redirect_url=${from.path}`); 
});

The reason for this is the difference between path and fullPath: (Based on Vue Router Documentation)

fullPath: The whole location including the search and hash. This
string is percentage encoded.
path: Percentage encoded pathname section of the URL.

